# I'm unable to connect with DNS seed list format to Atlas but works with old string format

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I recently moved from town and i have a different ISP. In my old house i used to connect to Atlas with

```
mongodb+srv://cluster0.wiiy6cz.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username <username>
```

and now it's not working, i have my new public ip Whitelisted on Atlas and the error message is
**pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The resolution lifetime expired after 21.123 seconds: Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.**

However, connection can be established with the old format string

```
mongodb://ac-tm89nv9-shard-00-00.wiiy6cz.mongodb.net:27017,ac-tm89nv9-shard-00-01.wiiy6cz.mongodb.net:27017,ac-tm89nv9-shard-00-02.wiiy6cz.mongodb.net:27017/myFirstDatabase?replicaSet=atlas-mqfpjp-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username <username> --password <password>
```

The only thing different now is my Internet Provider so i think it has to be something with the configuration of the DNS.

I already have installed pymongo[srv], i checked DNS of router configuration which is  DNS1: 45.71.46.194 DNS2: 8.8.8.8 DNS3: 0.0.0.0

So i'm curious about what is the problem here, i have already find a way around, but i really wish to know what is happening here